# Why the field in header is tt insted of tty?

Tags: command-line, ps

In the terminal

```
ps 
PID   TTY          TIME CMD
12555 pts/1    00:00:00 bash
22205 pts/1    00:00:00 ps
```

I want to display only four fields in the output info of ps command

```
ps -eo    pid,ppid,tty,cmd
PID  PPID TT       CMD
1     0   ?        /sbin/init text
2     0   ?        [kthreadd]
3     2   ?        [ksoftirqd/0]
```

Why the output info is not the following format?

```
PID  PPID TTY      CMD
1     0   ?        /sbin/init text
2     0   ?        [kthreadd]
3     2   ?        [ksoftirqd/0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tty`, `tt`, and `tname` are aliases, all of them show the controlling terminal. On the header:

- `tty`, and `tt` will show `TT`
- `tname` will show `TTY`

So, if you want `TTY` as the header, use `tname`:

```
ps -eo pid,ppid,tname,cmd
```